# Ajuda para Comunicar entre um Servidor e uma Aplicação Android

Tags: android, json, servidor

***Estou a desenvolver uma Aplicação em android Baseada em:***

- Adicionar/Enviar DATA para o Servidor
- Recolher/Receber DATA do Servidor
- Enviar e transmitir informação de Localização( Geolocalização )
- Partilhas de Perfis

***Eu fui sugerido a Usar JSON (Based Object) e passa-lo para android app. Mas não tenho ideia qualquer como :***

- Como e que uma App Android a correr no Telemóvel pede por "Objetos" JSON ?
- Como enviar DATA do android para o servidor ? Como este processo funciona.
- Se existe algum tipo de Programa especifico, ou e ao gosto de cada ?
- Se um Servidor "Caseiro" serve ?
- Se o Servidor tem que estar preparado para receber DATA JSON ?
- Se e muito complicado transmitir Android->Server / Server->android, informação de Localização (Geolocalização), quais os principais Procedimentos ?

> Apreciava mesmo com uma ajuda nestes tópicos, ou algum link de alguma
>   Pagina WeB que me pude-se auxiliar.

***Agradecia uma boa resposta :)
Um Muito Obrigado adiantado !***

Comment: Existe uma classe chamada JavaScriptInterface. Ela faz integração do JS com a aplicação nativa.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CqpBdCfZLUY

Comment: Vê se este vídeo tutorial ajuda: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e4eFBQmWs8Q . Download do projeto: https://github.com/kosalgeek/generic_asynctask